# Relation between reflections and rotations of a regular n-gon

Tags: group-theory, rotations, symmetry, reflection

I bumped into this relation between rotations and reflections of a regular n-gon:
$$xa = a^{n-1}x$$
where $x$ is a reflection and $a$ is a rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. I couldn't find any rigorous proof, so I'm trying to do it by myself, in a purely algebraic fashion.

First I tried it with some simple practical examples of triangles, squares, and hexagons, and it seems to hold water. Then I started trying to work it out.

It took me longer than it should have to notice that, in fact, $(xa)^{-1} = a^{n-1}x$. This is because $x^2 = id$ and $a^n = id$:

$$(xa)^{-1} = a^{-1}x^{-1} =a^{n-1}x^{-1}=a^{n-1}x.$$

However, proving that $xa = a^{n-1}x$ (assuming it is actually true) seems beyond my abilities... If I could prove that $a^{n-1}x$ is its own inverse, it would follow easily, but after several attempts I got nowhere. Ergo, either it is not true, or I'm missing something ^^

I'll be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: Let the vertices of the n-gon be $1,2,3,\ldots, n$ and see where they go under $xa$ and $a^{n-1}x$

Answer (score 1):

A rotation about the origin by an angle $2\theta$ is a combination of two reflections in the lines $L_1, L_2$ through the origin such that angle between $L_1, L_2$ is $\theta$. The lines $L_1, L_2$ are arbitrary as long as they pass through the center of rotation and make an angle $\theta$ between them. Let $x$ be the reflection in line $L$. Then the left hand side can be written as $R_L R_L R_{L_2}$ where $L_2$ makes an angle $\frac{\pi}{n}$ with $L$. Thus the result is just a reflection about $L_2$. The right hand side can similarly be written as $R_{L_1} R_L R_L$ where $L_1$ and $L$ make an angle $\frac{(n-1)\pi}{n}$ with $L$. Note that this is same as line $L_2$. Thus the two motions are the same.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there isn't any way of deriving the equation purely algebraically from what we know, like I derived the other one.

Comment: The group of symmetries of a regular polygon is the Dihedral group $D_{2n}$. We need to use the fact that $x$ is a reflection and $a$ is a rotation. I doubt if it can be derived from assuming $x^2 = e$ and $a^n = e$ alone.